# Sed or awk - Insert a new line after Matching pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file which contains multiple URLs. But unfortunately, all the URLs are in one line.

#### cat url_file

```
http://transfer.sh/PIGfk/my-file.002554http://transfer.sh/Ep9Md/my-file.002555http://transfer.sh/Ep9Md/my-file.002556http://transfer.sh/Ep9Md/my-file.002557
```

#### Expected output:

```
http://transfer.sh/PIGfk/my-file.002554
http://transfer.sh/Ep9Md/my-file.002555
http://transfer.sh/Ep9Md/my-file.002556
http://transfer.sh/Ep9Md/my-file.002557
```

Comment: Are you sure there's no invisible NUL character in there? Check with `sed -n l < url_file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's#(?<=.)(?=http://)#\n#g' url_file
```

**Explanation**

This uses a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to find substrings that begin with `http://` and place a newline (`\n`) before them.

It also uses a [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to only match when there is a character before the `http://`. In this way, no newline is insterted before the first url on a line. This will be extra handy if you end up with multiple lines.

**Update**

Prior to @steeldriver's awesome comment, a lookbehind wasn't used and I'd relied on `sed '1d'` to delete the first line.

Answer (score 3):

GNU grep

```
grep -oP 'http://.+?(?=http://|$)' url_file
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this GNU `sed` command:

```
sed 's,http://,\n&,g' url_file | tail -n +2
```

It looks for the pattern `http://` and insert a CR before it.

The `tail -n +2` skips the first (empty) line inserted by this sed command.

Comment: or `sed 's,\(.\)http://,\1\nhttp://,g'`

Comment: Thanks @JeffSchaller. I've never been able to do positive lookaheads with sed. That's super handy. You could also do `sed 's,\(.\)\(http://\),\1\n\2,g' url_file`
This way you don't have to re-write the http:// and it's more universal.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, why does your sed match the first URL? There are no characters before the first url to be matched by `\(.\)`

Comment: It *doesn't* match the *first* URL, as there's no character before the first one. That's why I mentioned it.

Comment: That `\n` is a GNU extension. With GNU `sed`, you can also do `sed 's|http://|\n&|2g'`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it all within `POSIX sed`:

```
$ sed -e '
   s|http://|\
&|2;P;D
' input.file
```

This places a newline before  the 2nd `http://` substring to be found in the current line. Then we perform the action "`print upto 1st newline, chop upto 1st newline, rinse & repeat`" till you run out of the pattern space. When only 1 http:// is left then the substitution does nothing, and that's the last print and delete action for the current record.

You can use `Perl` arrays to do the job:

```
perl -F'http:\/\/' -lane 'print "http://$_" for @F[1..$#F]' input.file
```

The first field `$F[0]` is empty so is skipped over while printing.

Answer (score 0):

I have done by below 3 methods

```
python

    #!/usr/bin/python
    import re
    k=open('filename','r')
    for i in k:
        print re.sub("http","\nhttp",i)



perl

perl -pne "s/http/\nhttp/g" filename



sed command

sed "s/http/\n&/g" filename
```

output

```
http://transfer.sh/PIGfk/my-file.002554
http://transfer.sh/Ep9Md/my-file.002555
http://transfer.sh/Ep9Md/my-file.002556
http://transfer.sh/Ep9Md/my-file.002557
```